# Appledoc and custom link description

Tags: ios, xcode, markdown, appledoc

If I'm doing something stupid, I'm sorry in advance. But I cannot identify my error.

Here is the code (header file):

```css
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

/**
 Represents a cover image. It can be a game cover, a trophy image or even a player avatar.

 It has three properties:

 - **NSMutableString uri**: the link that points to the image.
  - E.g.: [A Skyrim trophy image URI] (http://bit.ly/skyrimTrophyImageUri ).

 - **UIImage img**: the actual image. That is, the bitmap.
  - E.g.: 1A9A3826FB6B42C1B08824655A740620BC8E75F9.PNG

 - **ResolutionType resolution**: the image resolution, which comes from an enumeration of this class called __"ResolutionType"__.
  - E.g: SEN_75x41

*/

@interface NHOCCover : NSObject
```

The result:

[image]

[I'm following these instructions (at "Custom link descriptions" section).](http://gentlebytes.com/appledoc-docs-comments)

I also tried:

- [A Skyrim trophy image URI] (http://bit.ly/skyrimTrophyImageUri) (without spaces)
- [A Skyrim trophy image URI] ( http://bit.ly/skyrimTrophyImageUri ) (with spaces)

Maybe Xcode is messing up with the file? On a second related question, do you know if there is a way to block Xcode from automagically create links in its editor? (I mean to change the font color to blue and underline it).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Already answered you on github, adding the answer here as well for folks coming to this page: this is known issue with v2, will be fixed in 3.0. See https://github.com/tomaz/appledoc/issues/180

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 Represents a cover image. It can be a game cover, a trophy image or even a player avatar.

 It has three properties:

 - **NSMutableString uri**: the link that points to the image.
  - E.g.: [A Skyrim trophy image URI] (http://bit.ly/skyrimTrophyImageUri ).

 - **UIImage img**: the actual image. That is, the bitmap.
  - E.g.: 1A9A3826FB6B42C1B08824655A740620BC8E75F9.PNG

 - **ResolutionType resolution**: the image resolution, which comes from an enumeration of this class called __"ResolutionType"__.
  - E.g: SEN_75x41

*/
```

In your code there is a space between [A Skyrim trophy image URI] and (http://bit.ly/skyrimTrophyImageUri ), I guess that space is causing the problem.

The correct format is

```
[A Skyrim trophy image URI](http://bit.ly/skyrimTrophyImageUri )
```

I hope this might solve your problem. I know its been 9 months since, you asked this, but this might help others who have similar problem.